# Can you use mending to replace pages of a book with other pages?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips

Someone in my adventure wants to replace some maps in a book with different maps. The person removes the maps by cutting out the pages containing them and uses mending on the different maps to "repair" the missing pages. Can it do this? The motivation of the person is to mislead the party without leaving a trace.

Same question asking for a spell to do it: [How to replace pages of book with different pages, without leaving a trace of manipulation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/193048/how-to-replace-pages-of-book-with-different-pages-without-leaving-a-trace-of-ma/193049)

Comment: Neat question! I thought the answer would be easy, but reading the spell I became unsure. Let me make sure I understand though: the plan is to cut maps out of book A, cut other maps out of book B, and then put the maps from book A into book B (connecting the pages to the book at the point of cut with the *Mending* cantrip) as though they had always been there?

Comment: I've closed this a duplicate, the question here seems to be a clear example of the situation described there, and the accepted answer there answers this one directly.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Agreed. Well remembered! I tried searching for an answer myself, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: I am not sure if "combine arbitrary surfaces" and combine two items of the same material and break points is the same. It can repair "a broken chain link", so you have to use both parts of the same chain, to use the spell? And can't use the half an other broken chain of the same length as replacement material?

Comment: They aren't the same, in the sense that the latter is covered by the former rather than the two being of the same scope. A chain link is a single piece of a chain, so you can only repair a single link of a chain with one casting of *mending*.

Comment: [This](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7524/62294) meta discussion outlines when we close a question as a duplicate, and this one seems to me to fit quite well into the three criteria.